# Change Prescaler on the fly and use it immediately

Tags: c, stm32, hal

I managed to change the prescaler of the clock TIM2 on the fly by using

```
__HAL_TIM_SET_PRESCALER(&htim2,newValue);
```

However, until the counter resets to zero, it counts with the old pace.

Can I force the program to immediately use the new prescaler value?

I am using STM32L052K8Tx

Comment: You are using __HAL_ libraries so I assume you are working with STM micros, but can you give us some more details about the architecture? Usually the prescaler is a registered version of what you set, which doesn't get updated until the next timer overflow, however this is very dependant on the architecture.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what µC you're using, what you found in what chapter of its data sheet concerning your issue, and why it does not help.

Comment: Try to stop the timer, change the Prescaler and start the timer again

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't have it count in "fast units" all the time, then instead of changing the prescaler, change the delay?

Answer (score 3):

Refernce manual for STM32F10x (most STM32 have identical timers):

> PSC contains the value to be loaded in the active prescaler register at each update event
> (including when the counter is cleared through UG bit of TIMx_EGR register or through trigger
> controller when configured in “reset mode”).

You have to wait until the counter reaches zero. This event can be forced with the UG bit in EGR register, this will reset CNT and force reloads. If you need to keep CNT value, it's impossible to "tune" timer speed in real time using PSC without getting an Update event.

But you could try to use one timer as prescaler for another, running two timers in master-slave mode. ARR of the first timer can be reloaded without buffering (APRE bit = 0 in TIMx_CR1), and second timer would not be affected. See "Timer synchronization" chapter in refernce manual and examples, like TIM_Synchronization in the library.